# Tombstone State Tile Navigation Issues

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have secondary Tile for each page in my app. When i switch my app to Tombstone state, its failed to navigate corresponding page from Secondary Tile. App loading the previous page opened before deactivated.

Here the sample code for Secondary Tile creation.

```
if (!app.TileExists("/requestcalls"))
{
 StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
{
 BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Images/Tile.png", UriKind.Relative),
 Title = Request Calls",
 BackTitle = Request Calls",
 BackContent = "Add a new request",
```

};
    ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/requestcalls.xaml?", UriKind.Relative),   NewTileData);
   }

Comment: Can you provide a way to recreate the behaviour you're seeing and detail how you're trying to handle the tombstoned state?

Comment: Tombstone state is handled using Text Document attached to project and saving/retrieving values from the document. I used the above mentioned code to create a Tile which appears in the home screen. But not able to navigate the required form while clicking on tile in tombstone state. It works in Dormant state.

Comment: When i set ActivationPolicy="Resume" in WMAppManifest.xml page tile navigation is not working in Tombstone state, it reloads the last back stack page. It works fine with Dormant state with out reloading the page. If i dont set that property it reloads the page in Both states [Dormant state and Tombstone state].